# SQL Teradata - in query create new column that multiplies column by 2 if certain value is true

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a sql query I'm running that exports 2 columns, cost and months. The months column either has a value of 6 or 2. I want to create a new column that checks the months column and sees what the value is. If the month value is 6 then multiply the cost column by 2 and if the month value is 12 then just copy that same number in the cost column. Sample data:

```
cost                 months   
100                    6   
200                    12   
400                    6   

expected result:
cost           months       total   
100              6           200   
200              12          200   
400              6           800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple case statement should work:

```
select
cost,
months,
case when months = 6 then cost * 2
else cost
end as total
from <your table>
```

Comment: I have other columns I am pulling in as well and several joins. Where in my query do I put this?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  The case statement will be part of your select clause.  If that doesn't help you, edit your original post to include your query.